# How do I add ArrayLists into an ArrayList?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a region of data with a variable number of rows and columns. How would someone create a master arraylist and a temporary arraylist that can grab all the values of each row and then store that into the master arraylist and then clear the temporary arraylist? I don't know exactly how many items will go into either the master or the temporary and when this report is run on another day the number of items will likely be different so it needs to be flexible.

```
Sub arrayListsInArrayList()

    Dim MasterArrayList As Object
    Dim tempArrayList As Object
    Dim rowIndexer As Integer, rowCounter As Integer
    Dim colIndexer As Integer, colCounter As Integer

    Set MasterArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set tempArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    rowCounter = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
    colCounter = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Count

    For rowIndexer = 0 To rowCounter - 1

        tempArrayList.Clear

        For colIndexer = 0 To colCounter - 1
            tempArrayList.Add Range("A1").Offset(rowIndexer, colIndexer).Value
        Next colIndexer

        MasterArrayList.Add tempArrayList

    Next rowIndexer

End Sub
```

This code "works" but since the same-named tempArrayList is added so many times, I end up with repeated items. Is there a way to dynamically name the temporary arraylist? ie tempArrayList1, 2, etc.?

Comment: What are you trying to do.  Create an arraylist where each index is the array from a row, or add the values from each row such that each cell in the row is an arraylist item.  The former would emulate a 2d array, the latter would emulate a 1D array.

Comment: Are you assuming the source range isn't jagged? Or are you happy to have potentially empty elements within lists?

Comment: Essentially emulate a 2d array.

Comment: Source range could be jagged, but probably won't be. The empty or zero-ed elements shouldn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if simply adding ArrayLists of individual row values to a shared parent `ArrayList`, and clearing the tempArrayList in between, you can use `clone` method (this prevents the loss of values in parent when temp is cleared). The below ignores the source being jagged but you could use helper functions to determine instead last column per row.

Assuming empty elements are fine:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub testList()
    Dim src(), r As Long, c As Long
    Dim tempList As Object, masterList As Object

    Set tempList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set masterList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    src = Range("A1:C3").Value

    For r = LBound(src, 1) To UBound(src, 1)

        For c = LBound(src, 2) To UBound(src, 2)

           tempList.Add src(r, c)

        Next

        masterList.Add tempList.Clone

        tempList.Clear

    Next

    Stop
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, I'm going to try that.

Comment: Hopefully I understood your requirement. Any questions let me know.

Comment: I was really just missing the `.clone` call and things seem to be working just fine. Is there a way to dynamically name each of the items in the MasterArrayList? Maybe TempArrayList1, TempArrayList2, etc. or maybe based off of values in the spreadsheet?

Comment: You can't dynamically assign variables in that way I'm afraid.You could generate a structure where the "key" was a string dynamically named and the value the list (collection or dict most likely)

Comment: Would the values of the collection or dictionary still be writable?

Comment: Dictionary would be tmy preference as keys and values accessible. They wouldn't be variable names per se but would be key value pairs with keys standing in for variable names.